# How to enable write permissions on {index_name}_tmp file?

Tags: algolia

I'm trying to integrate Algolia with my Jekyll site by following the [instructions here](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-jekyll). The instructions say,

> Note that your API key should have write access to both the index_name and _tmp suffixed version of it (eg. your_index_name and your_index_name_tmp) in the previous example). This is due to the way we do atomic pushes by pushing to a temporary index and then renaming it.

However, the instructions don't explain how to enable write access to index_name and _tmp. As a result, when I try to push my index, I get this error:

> Algolia Error: API key cannot write to `{index_name}_tmp` index   In
>   order to do atomic pushes to your Algolia index, the plugin first
>   pushes to   a temporary index (suffixed with `_tmp`), then renames it.
>
> You see this error because the plugin wasn't able to push to that
>   `{index_name}_tmp` index, with the API key you provided.
>
> Make sure the API key you're using has rights to write on both your
>   index and   its `{index_name}_tmp` suffixed version.

In my Algolia Dashboard, the Admin API key is the same for both of my indexes (the regular one and the _tmp) one. How do I give my index_tmp write access so that I don't get this error message when pushing my index from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check that you're using your admin API key, as it should be sufficient to have write access to any index.

If you do not want to use your admin API key, you can create a new key specifically for Jekyll by going to your API key panel in the dashboard, and clicking "New API key" :

[image: New API key dialog]

Make sure you select the right ACLs at the bottom of the modal!

Comment: Thanks. I created a new API key and gave it full access, and it worked.